# Unable to install node using nvm on windows Access is denied

Tags: node.js, npm-install, nvm

I am trying to **install an specific versions of nodejs** from the command prompts:

```
"nvm install 12.21.0" and "nvm install v12.21.0"
```

And I get this error:
Could not retrieve https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/SHASUMS256.txt.

Because I use a proxy I use this to tell nvm about that:

```
"nvm proxy http://myproxy:8080"
```

And now I have this new error:
Access is denied.
Error while downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.21.0/win-x64//node.exe - invalid argument

I don't know **how can I fix it**

Comment: Have you tried installing using administrator ?

Answer (score 6):

1.Press `window key + x.`

2.Windows `PowerShell(Admin)`

3.Now use nvm normally, you won't get any error.